# PCI Express driver for embedded system

Tags: embedded, pci

We are developing an embedded system which will use a PC motherboard running Linux or Windows Embedded (have not decided which one). The board will read data from FPGA via PCI Express.
Novice question: do we have to develop our own PCIe driver or we can use something from the operating system? If we need our own, can you recommend a resource?

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what kind of data you want to transfer with the device.  If you just want register read/write you could just mmap /dev/mem and have a user space driver.

If you need to do DMA or interrupt then you'd likely have to write your custom driver.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unless your device corresponds to a standard device profile, you will need a custom device driver. Because you have not selected your operating system yet, your question about resources is pretty wide open still since obviously the OS selection directly affects driver design. For Windows you probably want to start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428). Under Linux, perhaps [here](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).